# Cannot convert input [00:00:00.020000] of type <class 'datetime.time'> to Timestamp

Tags: python, pandas, timestamp

My input data has a high resolution of datetime with seconds in fraction. For example, it should be
**1900-01-01 17:40:14.410000** instead of **1900-01-01 17:40:14**.

Apparently this format has not been recognized by the pandas or python. How should I successfully convert this to pandas recognized time stamp style.

Comment: For me working well `print (pd.to_datetime('1900-01-01 17:40:14.410000'))` -> `1900-01-01 17:40:14.410000`

Answer (score 2):

IIUC, you want a custom format:

```
pd.to_datetime('[00:00:00.020000]', format='[%H:%M:%S.%f]')
```

or, automagically:

```
pd.to_datetime('[00:00:00.020000]'.strip('[]'))
```

output: `Timestamp('2022-02-09 00:00:00.020000')`

As series:

```
s = pd.Series(['[00:00:00.020000]'])
pd.to_datetime(s.str.strip('[]'))
```

output:

```
0   2022-02-09 00:00:00.020
dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Answer (score 2):

Convert column or scalar to strings:

```
t = datetime.time(17, 40, 14, 410000)
print (pd.to_datetime(str(t)))
2022-02-09 17:40:14.410000
```

If column:

```
pd.to_datetime(df['col'].astype(str))
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand it correctly but pandas do have the style in the Timestamp class,
`myTime = pandas.Timestamp("1900-01-01 17:40:14.410000")` which you can access the attributes and methods of.

`myTime.year` should output `>>> 1900`
`myTime.time()` should output `>>> 17:40:14.410000` so on and so forth.